# Proper type for preventDefault on anchor tag and Next.js Link element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to `preventDefault()` on the `<Link>` element of Next.js

```
import Link from 'next/link'

...

const handleBackward = (event) => {
  if (history.length > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    router.back();
  }
}

return (
  <Link href="/" onClick={handleBackward}>Listing</Link>
)
```

However, I can’t find the proper type and get these errors:

```
(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>)
// Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic

(event: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>)
// Property 'preventDefault' does not exist on type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the correct type combination, this also works for `<a>` elements.

```
const handleBackward = (
  event: BaseSyntheticEvent<
    MouseEvent,
    EventTarget & HTMLAnchorElement,
    EventTarget
  >
) => {
  if (history.length > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    router.back();
  }
}
```